# When I `make` darknet with CUDA=1, `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda`occured. How to fix it without root permission

Tags: linux, makefile, cuda, darknet

I'm trying to train YOLOv4 with darknet on a computing cluster. But when I `make` the darknet, it occured that:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [darknet] Error 1
```

This computing cluster can load software with `module load`. For example, when I need CUDA10.2, just run `module load devel/cuda/10.2`.
So that means the files of CUDA still locate in the system directory, and I don't have the access to modify any of it.

In this case, how can I fix this problem?

More detail about this error:

```
[usr@*hpc darknet]$ make
chmod +x *.sh
g++ -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -Iinclude/ -I3rdparty/stb/include -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv4 2> /dev/null || pkg-config --cflags opencv` -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -DCUDNN -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -DGPU -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cudnn/include obj/image_opencv.o obj/http_stream.o obj/gemm.o obj/utils.o obj/dark_cuda.o obj/convolutional_layer.o obj/list.o obj/image.o obj/activations.o obj/im2col.o obj/col2im.o obj/blas.o obj/crop_layer.o obj/dropout_layer.o obj/maxpool_layer.o obj/softmax_layer.o obj/data.o obj/matrix.o obj/network.o obj/connected_layer.o obj/cost_layer.o obj/parser.o obj/option_list.o obj/darknet.o obj/detection_layer.o obj/captcha.o obj/route_layer.o obj/writing.o obj/box.o obj/nightmare.o obj/normalization_layer.o obj/avgpool_layer.o obj/coco.o obj/dice.o obj/yolo.o obj/detector.o obj/layer.o obj/compare.o obj/classifier.o obj/local_layer.o obj/swag.o obj/shortcut_layer.o obj/activation_layer.o obj/rnn_layer.o obj/gru_layer.o obj/rnn.o obj/rnn_vid.o obj/crnn_layer.o obj/demo.o obj/tag.o obj/cifar.o obj/go.o obj/batchnorm_layer.o obj/art.o obj/region_layer.o obj/reorg_layer.o obj/reorg_old_layer.o obj/super.o obj/voxel.o obj/tree.o obj/yolo_layer.o obj/gaussian_yolo_layer.o obj/upsample_layer.o obj/lstm_layer.o obj/conv_lstm_layer.o obj/scale_channels_layer.o obj/sam_layer.o obj/convolutional_kernels.o obj/activation_kernels.o obj/im2col_kernels.o obj/col2im_kernels.o obj/blas_kernels.o obj/crop_layer_kernels.o obj/dropout_layer_kernels.o obj/maxpool_layer_kernels.o obj/network_kernels.o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o -o darknet -lm -pthread `pkg-config --libs opencv4 2> /dev/null || pkg-config --libs opencv` -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -L/usr/local/cudnn/lib64 -lcudnn -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [darknet] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a machine with a GPU (and driver) installed, the `-lcuda` dependency can usually be satisfied because the driver installs the `libcuda.so` (or equivalent on windows) in the link search path (typically).

However on a machine with no GPU installed (e.g. a login node or build machine in a cluster) the driver won't be installed and therefore `libcuda.so` won't be in the "usual place".

In these situations, "stub" libraries are provided, usually in the `/stubs` directory off the CUDA toolkit library install directory (e.g. `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`).

Therefore, if you change your Makefile at [this line](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/Makefile#L52) to read:

```
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs -lcuda
```

it should allow that library to be located.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!  After I change that line in Makefile, the same problem occured again. very strange.  'LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs -lcuda'         After 'make':   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [darknet] Error 1

Comment: Does your `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` directory have a `stubs` directory?  Does that `stubs` directory have a `libcuda.so` file in it?  After you made the change to the `Makefile` and rerun make, what is the `g++` command that generated the error?  Does it reflect the change in the `LDFLAGS` ?

Comment: Yes, /opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cuda/10.2/lib64/libcuda.so do exists.

Comment: That's the output:
$ make
chmod +x *.sh
g++ -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -Iinclude/ -I3rdparty/stb/include -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv4 2> /dev/null || pkg-config --cflags opencv` -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -DCUDNN -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -DGPU -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cudnn/include obj/image_opencv.o obj/http_stream.o obj/gemm.o obj/utils.o obj/dark_cuda.o obj/convolutional_layer.o obj/list.o obj/image.o

Comment: obj/activations.o obj/im2col.o obj/col2im.o obj/blas.o obj/crop_layer.o obj/dropout_layer.o obj/maxpool_layer.o obj/softmax_layer.o obj/data.o obj/matrix.o obj/network.o obj/connected_layer.o obj/cost_layer.o obj/parser.o obj/option_list.o obj/darknet.o obj/detection_layer.o obj/captcha.o obj/route_layer.o obj/writing.o obj/box.o obj/nightmare.o obj/normalization_layer.o obj/avgpool_layer.o obj/coco.o obj/dice.o obj/yolo.o obj/detector.o obj/layer.o obj/compare.o obj/classifier.o obj/local_layer.o obj/swag.o obj/shortcut_layer.o obj/activation_layer.o obj/rnn_layer.o obj/gru_layer.o obj/rnn.o

Comment: obj/local_layer.o obj/swag.o obj/shortcut_layer.o obj/activation_layer.o obj/rnn_layer.o obj/gru_layer.o obj/rnn.o obj/rnn_vid.o obj/crnn_layer.o obj/demo.o obj/tag.o obj/cifar.o obj/go.o obj/batchnorm_layer.o obj/art.o obj/region_layer.o obj/reorg_layer.o obj/reorg_old_layer.o obj/super.o obj/voxel.o obj/tree.o obj/yolo_layer.o obj/gaussian_yolo_layer.o obj/upsample_layer.o obj/lstm_layer.o obj/conv_lstm_layer.o obj/scale_channels_layer.o obj/sam_layer.o obj/convolutional_kernels.o obj/activation_kernels.o obj/im2col_kernels.o obj/col2im_kernels.o obj/blas_kernels.o

Comment: obj/crop_layer_kernels.o obj/dropout_layer_kernels.o obj/maxpool_layer_kernels.o obj/network_kernels.o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o -o darknet -lm -pthread `pkg-config --libs opencv4 2> /dev/null || pkg-config --libs opencv` -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs -lcuda -L/usr/local/cudnn/lib64 -lcudnn -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [darknet] Error 1

Comment: So your CUDA install is at: `/opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cuda/10.2/`  ?  If so, you need to adjust for that.  Based on what you've now indicated, you may want to try changing that line in your Makefile to: `LDFLAGS+= -L/opt/bwhpc/common/devel/cuda/10.2/lib64 -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lcuda`

Comment: Yes, after I used 'module load /devel/cuda/10.2', cuda can be used in this path. So, that means I need to adjust all the path in Makefile to this actual path of these : '/opt/bwhpc/common/devel/...' before I 'make'? I will try it. Thanks a lot!